# Where is the palette knife located in photoshop cs6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm following a tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialbunch.com/photoshop/animation/animated-snow-fall.shtml) and i'm using photoshop cs6 but i can't seem to find the palette knife. Is there an alternative way of achieving thesame result in photoshop cs6.

Comment: Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site, review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CC, which should be the same as CS6:
Go to "FILTERS" (top menu), then "Filter Gallery"
All the filters are sorted by time and the one you want should be in the "Artistic Folder" .

[image]